# Getting BeanDefinitionStoreException starting Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am getting another error starting up my Spring MVC application.  This all started when I converted it to a Maven application, but I don't think Maven has anything to do with the problem.  I am seeing this in Tomcat 8.0.30.

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues.get(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
```

Here again is my applicationContext.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd">
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resources location="WEB-INF/pages/images/" mapping="/images/**" />

    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="home" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://10.128.219.28:3306/ghscom_ghs86" />
        <property name="username" value="someUsername" />
        <property name="password" value="somePassword" />
    </bean>
</beans
```

Comment: if it is an eclipse project, try this: right click to the project > select Maven > Update Project, wait until all maven dependencies had been downloaded.  And then run the project.

Comment: This didn't work.

Comment: Some spring jars version mismatch error, check the dependencies versions in maven. After checking versions in pom.xml, delete your local maven repository jars and rebuild/redownload all dependencies. Hope it will resolve this issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Amit K Bist solved my problem.  It was indeed a Maven dependency mismatch.